# running Window managers on OpenVZ - limitations?

Tags: openvz

I'm running a Linux Desktop (Ubuntu MATE) on an OpenVZ VPS (& thinlinc)

It appears this is not something that is supported because I run into various problems; for instance applications can't escalate (Ubuntu Software center) - many things don't work with standard user (root is somewhat better).

There's also chrome that needs to be run with --no-sandbox regardless of the user account.

I suspect there's things that are broken from running under OpenVZ, I'd just like to know what is the cause and exactly how much stuff I can expect to be broken.